# On Delete Cascade, On Delete Set Null

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, ddl

While creating a table I missed to use `ON DELETE` condition in foreign key constraint. I took the id column from other table (reference table)

If I drop the reference table what will happen to the newly created table.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Clearly explain the scenario /  what  and how you are trying to delete etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `ON DELETE` action for a foreign key constraint only affects `DELETE` statements.

If you want to `DROP` a table that is *referenced* by another table, you can only do that if you use `DROP TABLE ... CASCADE CONSTRAINTS` which will drop the *incoming* foreign key constraints as well, i.e. the constraints defined on other tables referencing the one to be dropped. That option will not drop those other tables, only the foreign key constraints.

Comment: Hai In the following i can't create a view please tell me what's the error 
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW emp_mvw
REFRESH COMPLETE
ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT first_name, salary, department_id FROM employees
 WHERE department_id = 50;

Comment: @SRamPrakash: don't ask new questions in comments. Klick on the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button instead.